# C# - Drag and Drop from picture box earlier code-created

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, picturebox

I am trying to code a drag and drop system with pictureboxes. I did this earlier, except this time, I created the pictureboxes by code and not in the designer.

```
DASporter dasporter = new DASporter();
        List<int> landids = dasporter.getLandenBySport(1);
        DALand daland = new DALand();
        Land land = null;

        PictureBox[] landenfotos = new PictureBox[landids.Count];
        int teller = 80;
        for (int i = 0; i <= landids.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            land = daland.getLand(landids[i]);
            landenfotos[i] = new PictureBox();
            landenfotos[i].Name = "Picturebox" + land.Id.ToString();
            landenfotos[i].Location = new Point(70, teller);
            landenfotos[i].Tag = land.Naam;
            landenfotos[i].Size = new Size(70, 70);
            landenfotos[i].Image = Image.FromFile("images/" + land.Vlag);
            landenfotos[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.Controls.Add(landenfotos[i]);
            teller += 60;
        }
```

If you create them in the designer, you can use the eventmanager to search the right event. Now, I can't use this so i need an alternative.

Anyone who had this problem too and got it solved? I can't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can add event handlers easily by typing

```
landenfotos[i].MouseMove +=<Tab><Tab>
```

Pressing `<Tab>` twice after `+=` will create an event handler automatically.

It will complete the line to

```
landenfotos[i].MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(SomeMethodName_MouseMove);
```

and add the method

```
void SomeMethodName_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And of course Intellisense will show you all the available events to choose from :-)